# Effective C++ Item 11 handle assignment to self

Tags: c++, effective-c++

I am reading this book and I do not understand the difference between two pieces of code.

```
class Bitmap{...};
class Widget
{
    ...
private:
    Bitmap* m_pb;
};

Widget& Widget::operator=(const Widget& rhs)
    {
        if (this == &rhs)
        {
            return *this;  // if a self-assignment, do nothing
        }
        delete pb;
        pb = new Bitmap(*rhs.m_pb);
        return *this;
    }
```

Mr. Meyers says:

> if the "new Bitmap" expression yields an exception, the Widget will
>   end up holding a pointer to a deleted Bitmap.

Does it mean that the *pd* pointer points to NULL?

```
Widget& Widget::operator=(const Widget& rhs)
{
    Bitmap* temp = pb;
    pb = new Bitmap(*rhs.pb);
    delete temp;
    return *this;
}
```

Mr. Meyers says:

> Now, if "new Bitmap" throws an exception, pb pointer remains
>   unchanged.

As far as I know, *temp* pointer points to the same memory address as *pb* pointer. If the "new" throws an exception, *pb* will point to NULL and the next sentence will delete the Bitmap. Is that correct? I do not see the difference between these implementations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's about being 'effective' - copying bitmap should be avoided, because it's not necessary. Also - think how your code would have to change, if `Widget` would hold two or more pointers, some depending on values in others...

Comment: _"the Widget will end up holding a pointer to a deleted Bitmap."_ What's unclear about this? Why do you think it has anything to do with "NULL"?

Answer (score 5):

> Does it mean that the pd pointer points to NULL?

No. Yes. Maybe. The pointer has been `delete`d, you can't rely on what it does or does not point to, so you're on the fast-track to undefined behaviour.

> As far as I know, temp pointer points to the same memory address as pb pointer. If the "new" throws an exception, pb will point to NULL and the next sentence will delete the Bitmap. Is that correct?

If `new` throws here, `pb` will be in the same state that it was before and the next expression will not be executed.

> I do not see the difference between these implementations.

In the first snippet, `pb` points to a `delete`d pointer if `new` throws.
In the second snippet, `pb` points to the same valid object it used to if `new` throws.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When you say "the next expression will not be executed", you mean "delete temp" expression. Don´t you?

Comment: @J.PG if an exception is thrown, execution of that function will cease and the exception will be propagated.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you assign `temp` to the same memory location as `pb` doesn't influence `pb` in any manner. In the next line, if `Bitmap` constructor will throw an exception the control won't reach the assignment part, thus `pb` will remain unchanged.